# Change from Shared to Unshared connection

Tags: ibm-connections, ibm-was

How can I change from shared connections( which is by default) to unshared connection. ?

And how to ensure if the connection to data source which I m using is unshared?

Comment: can you specify which service you are referring to?  do you mean files?

Answer (score 0):

You need to define resource reference, either via annotation or deployment descriptor for example:

Annotation:

```
@Resource(shareable=false)
DataSource datasource;
```

Deployment descriptor:

```
  <resource-ref>
    <res-ref-name>jdbc/mydbdatasourceRef</res-ref-name>
    <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
    <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
    <res-sharing-scope>Unshareable</res-sharing-scope>
  </resource-ref>
```

And if you use deployment descriptor make sure that lookup is via reference - `java:comp/env/jdbc/mydbdatasourceRef` - not the global jndi name.

**UPDATE**

You dont need to set `defaultConnectionTypeOverride` or `globalConnectionTypeOverride`, they allow you to set sharing without references, or override references.

> **defaultConnectionTypeOverride** - The defaultConnectionTypeOverride property changes the default sharing value for a connection pool. This
>   property enables you to control connection sharing for direct
>   look-ups. If resource references are configured for a data source or
>   connection factory they take precedence over this property and the
>   resource reference settings are used.
>
> **globalConnectionTypeOverride** - The value specified for the globalConnectionTypeOverride custom property takes precedence over all
>   of the other connection sharing settings. For example, if you set this
>   property to unshared, all connection requests are unshared for both
>   direct look-ups and resource reference lookups.

For more details check [Connection pool custom properties](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SS7JFU_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.express.doc/ae/rdat_conpoolcustprops.html?cp=SS7JFU_8.5.5%2F1-17-7-4&lang=en) in the Knowledge Center.

Comment: Gas.... do we also need to set two custom properties in Connection pool in data source; globalConnectionTypeOverride and defaultConnectionTypeOverride?